# Integral of $(\log x)^2e^x$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

How to calculate $\int_0^\infty e^x(\log x)^2$. I  have tried putting $x=\log(t)$ but can't reach the solution.

Comment: Did you mean $$\int_0^{\infty} dx \, e^{-x} \log^2{x}$$

Comment: Yes i mean the same

Comment: Then please start a new question with that so that the answer below is preserved.

Comment: Okk i will put the new question

Answer (score 1):

This integral diverges. It is easy to see this from the fact that the integrand does not approach zero as $x \rightarrow \infty$, but I will continue with a  more precise proof. First, the integral is improper in two ways; one limit of integration is infinite and there is an infinite singularity in the region of integration. Splitting up the integral yields $$\int_0^\infty e^x(\log(x))^2dx = \int_0^1e^x(\log(x))^2dx + \int_1^\infty e^x(\log(x))^2 dx$$ Considering just the second integral, $\log(x)^2 \geq 1$ for $x \geq e$ so $log(x)^2e^x \geq e^x$ for $x \geq e$. By the comparison theorem, $$\int_e^\infty e^x dx \leq \int_e^\infty e^x (\log(x))^2 dx$$ Since $\int_0^\infty e^x dx = \lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}e^x-1=\infty$, both integrals diverge and hence the integral you seek diverges, as $\int_1^e e^x (\log(x))^2 $ is finite.

Comment: i mean log^2(x) not log(x)^2